# How to make Alphanumeric editext in capital case in android

Tags: android

In my application i have an edittext in which a user can Alphanumeric string. Now the point is i want that whatever the aplhanumeric or alphabetic string  he types that should be converted into the capital case.
For ex: if the edittext input is like:

> sdhq8273dyp3

In editext when user types it should be converted to captial case

> SHHQ8273DYP3

Is there any way. if in XML i am setting the Attribute **android:textAllCaps="true"** it is giving me the error. 
So how can we make the Editext aplhanumeric character to uppercase.

Comment: What error you are getting using `android:textAllCaps` ?

Comment: Number format exception

Comment: If any of the answers meet your expectations, mark it as an answer.

Comment: if you want to force user to write in uppercase letters on your edittext, you just need to add android:inputType="textCapCharacters" and your keyboard on device will set into uppercase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 android:capitalize="characters"
 android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

This working fine in my case.

Comment: As ** android:capitalize="characters"** is deprecated.     This two lines works for me :   **android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"**

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputMethod

You'll probably want

```
android:inputMethod="textCapCharacters"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

You can even do this in your java code

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Comment: Cool. It seems to be a copy of my answer.

Comment: What a co-incidence! But you answered after me, I guess @xenteros

Answer (score 2):

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

These two might be useful

Comment: Cool. It seems to be a copy of my answer.

Comment: It's not. Let me prove. My answer was posted before your. End of proof.

Answer (score 2):

You can wite this in java file.

```
   edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

or you can use this is xml

```
   android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

Comment: It is a copy of my answer.

Comment: I was writing my answer but you posted same before me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set it programmatically and it is for api level 14 and above only. below it you have to manually implement it.

```
editText.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                   + android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

I found your problem.  `android:textAllCaps`is for textview and not edittext. see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAllCaps)